# Is it safe to use getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c

I've been told that I should use fgets and sscanf instead of scanf and I'm just wondering if there are any problems associated with getchar() and putchar() that are similar to the problems with scanf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## This is safe

The functions `getchar` and `putchar` (unlike `gets`, `scanf`, `fgets`) use `char` types, not `char *`, so there's no risk of buffer overflow since there's no buffer (there is a buffer since I/O is buffered, but you don't control its size and it's properly managed by the C library)

Be careful when using them in a loop not to recreate security issues in your own code, the ones that you wanted to avoid.

If your goal is to read a string using `getchar`, you'll have to create a loop to store characters. If you aren't careful, you could end up with the same kind of buffer overflow issues. The problem has just moved somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with `scanf` is that it's pattern language doesn't always allow enough control, particularly if you want to restrict input to a line-oriented format. A secondary problem, which can be overcome by specifying size limits, is that by default string fields are of unlimited size and can therefore overflow their destination buffers.

`getchar` does not suffer from either of those issues,, for reasons which I hope are obvious.